# Visualizing document citations in a graph

Tags: charts, citations

Is there any tool which draws a citation graph for a group of related papers? (it doesn't matter the format of papers - PDF, Word, etc - it also doesn't matter if the software doesn't perform parsing of citations)

Answer (score 1):

[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) (specifically, its [dot](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf) tool) might be suitable. It's generates graph visualisations in formats including Postscript and PNG from a source that looks like this (in its simplest form):

```
digraph citations {
    "paper 1" -> "paper 2";
    "paper 2" -> "paper 3";
    "paper 1" -> "paper 4";
    …
}
```

It's good at generating a human-readable visualisation if the graph is planar, less so otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [PaperScope](http://paperscope.sourceforge.net/).

> PaperScope is a tool for graphically exploring the Astrophysics Data System (ADS) which is a database of published astrophysics papers (http://adsabs.harvard.edu/).  PaperScope is extremely useful for identifying the citation/reference relationships between papers, and enables the user to visualize these relationships to make locating papers of interest easier.  Use it for constructing reference or citation chains, as well as identifying common references/citations between several key papers.  It is a tool designed to simplify the process of searching for relevant papers to an astrophysics researcher whether they be a professor, post doc, or  student.